# need javascript or jquery for three word with tow speperated comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My project requirement for regex search string are as  following 
1) there are three words allow with two comma (e.g - DivisioName,StoreName,CameraName)
2) allow (*,*,*) means all Division, all store and all camera
3) Word conatains only (-) character but always starts with alfabetic character
4) if i put * then no other word or character allowed- whole word becomes (*) and initialy comma should apply.

Allowed Text Cases are as following...

```
text1,text2
text-1,text-2,text-3
text-1
text1,
text1,text2
text1,text2,
text1,,
,
,,
,text,
*,*,*
*,*
*
*,*,
```

Not Allowed Text Cases are as following...

```
-text1,text2,text3,
text-1,text2,text3,text4
,,,
a,a,,
-text1,text2
-text-1,text-2,text-3
-
-,-
```

Please help me for this solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I have tried for this : /^\s*(?:\w+\s*,\s*){2,}(?:\w+\s*)$/,  /^(?:\w+,){2,}(?:\w+)$/ but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^,?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+,){0,2},?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/11

Comment: I'd advise against answering blatant code requests like this. They're not likely to help future visitors.

Comment: This Case is goring to fail in this regx: a,a,,

Comment: I think last comma take as string so not match, so last word also want take comma or in all word expression need to check that it should not allowed comma as character

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to allow the string like this (*,*,*), (Div1,Store1,Cam10-AHM_Ch) - so need to allow character (*,-,_). Also word can not start with (- and _) these characters. Please help me out for this. Thanks

Comment: @vks - Thanks for the Help. I have edit my question and put whole requirement of my project. Please help me out to crack that regex.